# Pesquisar no banco de dados e passar para um listview c# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, windows, listview

estou desenvolvendo um projeto e por ser nova na área estou com bastante dúvidas e dificuldades. Meu problema é o seguinte:
Tenho um form para administrar as notas a prazo de uma empresa, ao abrir o form, o usuário precisa digitar (ou pesquisar) o código do cliente. E ao digitar, ele listará todos as notas que estão no ID desse cliente. Certo?

Porém, não estou conseguindo pesquisar pelo ID do cliente.
Como posso fazer?

Abaixo segue um trecho do código para buscar um cliente:

```
    private void Txt_Busca_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt_Busca.Text.Trim().Equals(String.Empty))
        {
            PreencherLista(lista);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            var listResult = new List<EntidadeViewPesquisaCliente>(from p in lista where p.Nome.ToLower().Contains(txt_Busca.Text.Trim().ToLower()) select p);
            PreencherLista(listResult);
        }

    }
```

Meu código está assim:

using Entidades.Entidades;
using Entidades.Vendas;
using Negocio.NotasNG;
using projeto.Modulos;
using projeto.Notas;
using projeto.Pesquisas;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace projeto.Vendas
{
    public partial class FrmAdmNotas : Form
    {
        public List lista = new List();
        public int iRetorno = 0;
        public FrmAdmNotas()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void FrmAdmNotas_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form = new Form()
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
            ShowInTaskbar = false,
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen,
            TopMost = true,
            Top = 0,
            Left = 0
        };

        PrepararLista(lista);
        LimparCampos();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Botão para pesquisar o cliente - Abre outro Form e o usuário digita o nome do cliente, buscando pelo código.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Bt_PesquisarCliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lista = new NotasNG().ListarEntidadeViewPesquisaCliente();
        //Verifica se a lista está vazia
        if (lista.Count < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sem dados para serem exibidos!", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            return;
        }

        //Passa a lista para o formulário genérico de pesquisa de cliente;

        var frmPesquisaC = new FrmPesquisaCliente("Listagem de Clientes");
        frmPesquisaC.lista = lista;
        frmPesquisaC.ShowDialog();

        var iRetorno = frmPesquisaC.iRetorno;
        //iRetorno = 0
        if (iRetorno < 1)
            return;

        txt_CodigoCliente.Text = iRetorno.ToString();

        Txt_CodigoCliente_Validating(txt_CodigoCliente, new CancelEventArgs());
        bt_PesquisarCliente.Focus();

    }

    private void Txt_CodigoCliente_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //Verifica se está vazio
        if (txt_CodigoCliente.Text.Trim().Equals(string.Empty))
            return;

        var oCliente = new NotasNG().BuscarCliente(txt_CodigoCliente.Text.Trim());
        //AQUI ESTÁ A DÚVIDA - PRECISO BUSCAR AS NOTAS DO CLIENTE 
        var oNota = new NotasNG().BuscarNotas(Convert.ToInt32(txt_CodigoCliente.Text.Trim()));


        txt_NomeCliente.Text = oCliente.Nome;
        foreach (var item in oNota.NotaLista)
        {
            PreencherListaNota(item);
        }

        Txt_CodigoCliente_TextChanged(txt_CodigoCliente, new EventArgs());


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Limpa os campos de dados!
    /// </summary>
    private void LimparCampos()
    {
        txt_CodigoCliente.Text = string.Empty;
        iRetorno = 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Prepara a lista para ser exibida
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list"></param>
    public void PrepararLista(List<EntidadeViewPesquisaNota> list)
    {
        lvlListagemNotas.Clear();
        lvlListagemNotas.View = View.Details;
        lvlListagemNotas.Columns.Add("Nº da Nota", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lvlListagemNotas.Columns.Add("Nº do Funcionário", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lvlListagemNotas.Columns.Add("Nº de Controle", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lvlListagemNotas.Columns.Add("Data da Emissão", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lvlListagemNotas.Columns.Add("Valor Pago", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lvlListagemNotas.Columns.Add("Desconto", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        lvlListagemNotas.Columns.Add("Data Pagamento", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var linha = new string[7];
            linha[0] = item.NotaID.ToString();
            linha[1] = item.FuncionarioID.ToString();
            linha[2] = item.NumeroNota;
            linha[3] = item.DataEmissao.ToString();
            linha[4] = item.ValorPago.ToString();
            linha[5] = item.Desconto.ToString();
            linha[6] = item.DataPagamentoFinal.ToString();
            var itmx = new ListViewItem(linha);
            lvlListagemNotas.Items.Add(itmx);
        }
        Funcoes.ListviewColor(lvlListagemNotas);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Preenche a lista de Notas com os dados da nota
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    private void PreencherListaNota(Nota obj)
    {

        var linha = new string[7];
        linha[0] = obj.NotaID.ToString();
        linha[1] = obj.FuncionarioID.ToString();
        linha[2] = obj.NumeroNota.ToString();
        linha[3] = obj.DataEmissao.ToString();
        linha[4] = obj.ValorPago.ToString();
        linha[5] = obj.Desconto.ToString();
        linha[6] = obj.DataPagamentoFinal.ToString();

        var itmx = new ListViewItem(linha);
        lvlListagemNotas.Items.Add(itmx);

        Funcoes.ListviewColor(lvlListagemNotas);
    }
    private void LvlListagemNotas_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bt_Abrir_Click(bt_Abrir, new EventArgs());

    }


    private void Bt_Abrir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }



    private void Txt_CodigoCliente_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ClienteID;
        bool success = Int32.TryParse(txt_CodigoCliente.Text.Trim(), out ClienteID);

        if (success)
        {
            var listResult = new List<EntidadeViewPesquisaNota>(from p in lista where p.ClienteID == ClienteID select p);
            PrepararLista(listResult);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("O texto digitado não é um número inteiro.");
        }


    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

É só pegar o valor digitado e fazer a busca pela propriedade `Id` levando em consideração que o nome da sua propriedade no modelo seja mesmo "Id":

```js
      
int Id;
bool success = Int32.TryParse(txt_Busca.Text.Trim(), out Id);

if (success)
{
var listResult = new List<EntidadeViewPesquisaCliente>(from p in lista where p.Id == Id select p); 
PreencherLista(listResult); 
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("O texto digitado não é um número inteiro.");
}
```

Comment: Victor, eu segui como me falou, porém não exibiu as linhas pretendidas. Você poderia me ajudar a achar o erro? Editei a pergunta

Comment: Era só um parêntesis que digitei a mais, atualizei a resposta, basta remover antes do erro.